# Android noclassdeffounderror on new project

Tags: java, android, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I have the android development tools running on my mac, and I need to build a project using JSON-RPC.

I'm using this library:
http://software.dzhuvinov.com/json-rpc-2.0-client.html

I take the following steps:
- Download both the client and base jar file.
- Drag them into the libs folder.
- Paste the sample code from the site in to the main activity's onCreate function.

After that I run the test app in the simulator, which produces the following error message:

> 12-08 17:41:40.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2119):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2Request

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: Make sure you add the jar files to your classpath.

Comment: I've tried these suggestions. When I try to edit the runtime configurations, the only tabs is see for the android runtime configurations are 'Android', 'Target', 'Common'.

Comment: What other tabs do you expect to see?

Comment: Isn't that where you're supposed to add the library to the runtime classpath?

Answer (score 0):

right click project > Properties > java Build Path > Add External JARs then navigate to where you have your jar and add it.

Comment: I've already tried all these suggestions, but it doesn't work, could there be a problem with java or a plugin I need to install that I'm missing?

Comment: I found this blog post but since i don't know which of the many scenarios stated may be cause of your problem, you will have to go through it to understand which solution works for you. http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Comment: I would also advice you go through the code you pasted in you `onCreate()` method to be sure it's not the problem.